# Fixing wheel tracks on lawn

Tags: lawn

Ok, I had 60yo oak taken down on my back yard. Not sure how to do it properly without damage but guys drove bucket truck and:

1. Got stuck - there is 1+ft holes in a ground below topsoil
2. While driving into yard and back left about 6 inch deep tracks in lawn.
3. Bunch of holes left from chunks falling down.

I was fine with holes from falling limbs, not a biggie to fix but got really disappointed with those tracks. I have not clue how to fix it. It looks like this on a ground:

[image]

Those tracks go for long way (I have .7 acre and it is on backyard). I can imagine how local damages can be worked but long imprints from driving on it?

They said they will bring topsoil and fix all but I'm really sceptical about it..

Question is: How do I fix this "waves"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no easy way to fix this.  If you had access to a tractor or bobcat with a bucket you could run the bucket along the ground and shear off the bumps above ground.  Then back fill with soil, compact and overseed with grass seed.

Things to check include:

- the soil type and how wet the soil is. If the soil is soft and wet now you might want to wait until it gets drier before doing the cut and fill.
- if possible you should fill the depressions with the same type of soil so the drainage remains the same.
- if there is any chance you will be moving heavy equipment through the area again then maybe you need an access path. Consider using gravel instead of soil to back fill the ruts for an inexpensive path